# Delete multiple issue/PR comments via the GitHub API

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-api, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to delete multiple PRs/issues comments at once with GitHub Actions over the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3).

Is there a way to do this without showing the delete message multiple times like the following image?

[image: delete message 4 times]

For example, I thought there may be a way to delete multiple issue/pull request review comments with one request that shows a message like `<user> deleted n comments from <users whose comments have been deleted>`?

Currently, I am deleting messages using the following curl command in a loop:

```
echo "$ids" | while read -r id; do
    curl -X "DELETE" -s -H "authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" -H "User-Agent: Actions-<username>/<reponame>" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" "https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<reponame>/issues/<issue number>/comments/$id"
done
```

If it is a pull request, I use `pulls` with instead of `issues`.

I also think that there is a rate limit preventing the deletion of that many commands in such a short time.

See the docs for deleting an [issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#delete-a-comment) and a [pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#delete-a-comment) comment.

[**Context**]

I want to create a command that clears multiple messages at once. If somebody enters `/clear 5` for example, the latest 5 messages will be deleted.

Comment: Do you need to do it from a GitHub action? Pull requests won't allow you modify the repository; issues will, but maybe it's better if it's done directly from a client.

Comment: Yes, I only want to delete Issue/PR comments.

Comment: then it's probably better if you just run a loop and use the curl client or any other.

Comment: The problem is that I get so many messages that are displaying that the bot deleted a message.

Comment: I think we need more information here. Are you deleting something from a github action, and that action also causes another deletion? Can you show that action that's been triggered?

Comment: The action is triggered by a issue/pr review comment with the content `/clear <number>` and deletes <number> messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it. It is a core feature from Github to create a timeline event on any action (like push, comment, rebase, merge, etc). That's a standard placeholder.

https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/managing-disruptive-comments#deleting-a-comment

Also, it looks like Github doesn't support BATCH operations currently.

So, NO and NO at the moment :(